# Exception throws while printing invoice in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, plugins, printing, flutter-desktop

i am currently working on printing invoice on desktop application using the following plugin.
https://pub.flutter-io.cn/packages/printing

When i execute print command to print invoice pdf, the code throws exception [ Unhandled Exception: Exception: FormatException: Unexpected extension byte (at offset 0)
]. Can't get it what is this exception and how to solve it.

Please help me out. Thankx

Comment: the package you are using its not support for flutter desktop application. its only support for Android iOS and web

Comment: Web support is actually desktop support. It is already printing a simple Hello World text. but not printing my own designed invoice pdf

Comment: Can you post some code?